# Load Selected DataFrame Columns in MS SQL SERVER in python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

My dataframe columns store in data variable.

```
data=df[['FirstName','City','PhoneNo']]
```

Establish the MS SQL SERVER Connection.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = pyodbc.connect('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@ip_address:port/dbName; DRIVER={ODBC 
Driver 17 for SQL Server}')
print(data.head())
data.to_sql('demo', engine, if_exists='replace',method='multi',index=False,chunksize=20)
```

In this case my Output is :

```
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

And I'm also try second approach which gives different error.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import urllib

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=username:password@ip:port;DATABASE=dbName")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
print(data.head())
data.to_sql('demo', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False,chunksize=20)
```

In this case my *data.head()* is working print top 5 data, but it show different error.

```
pyodbc.OperationalError:('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

One more Thing

```
my  cat /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini  is empty or
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[SQLite]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=libsqliteodbc.so
Setup=libsqliteodbc.so
UsageCount=1

[SQLite3]
Description=SQLite3 ODBC Driver
Driver=libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=libsqlite3odbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

And When we check my driver on jupyter notebook with the help of pyodbc package method it show the driver name like

```
pyodbc.drivers()
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

So how to handle this problem pls help anyone.

So to integrated this code ....!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/home/saurabh/AlphaaAI/material.csv')

data=df.head(20)

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=ip,port;Database=dbname;UID=?;PWD=?')
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
data.to_sql('tablename', schema='dbo', con = engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', method='multi',chunksize=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-pyodbc) more closely.

For the first example `driver=` must be lowercase and preceded by a question mark.

For the second example you need to specify the username and password as `UID=` and `PWD=`, and the server/port as `SERVER=servername,port`.